# Ajax BeginForm is replacing the Layout file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Ajax BeginForm is replacing the Layout file.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Patient",
        new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
     }))
    {
<div id="grid">
       <table >

     <tr>

            <th>
                Name (English) :-
            </th>
            <th>
              <input type="text" name="FName"  />
            </th></tr>
          <tr>

            <th>
             Last Name  :-
            </th>
            <th>
              <input type="text" name="LName"  />
            </th></tr>

          <input type="submit" value="Search      " /></th><th></th></tr>
      </table>
</div>
    }
```

Jquery

```
 $('#form1').ajaxForm(function (result) {
     alert("IN Ajax Form");
     $("#grid").html(result);
  });
```

I have also added jQuery.js and the http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js scripts.

From the second request, Request.IsAjaxRequest() method returns false.

Also the alert("IN Ajax Form") is firing only for the first request.

Please help me.

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your trying to do here. You `Ajax.BeginForm()` does not specify a `UpdateTargetId` (what are you returning from the `Search()` method?). And what is the other form you have in the view (the one with `id="form1"`). And for the `Ajax.BeginForm()` to work you need `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` - is that included?

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) Just added UpdateTargetId  and its working.